# Are any of these sequents provable using ND rules?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

$$\large\begin{array}{ll}1. & \vdash \exists x~(Px\to\forall y~Py))\\2. & \forall x~\exists y~(Px\to Qy)\vdash \exists y~\forall x~(Px\to Qy)\\3. & Sj, \forall x~(\lnot(x=j)\to Sx)\vdash \forall x~Sx\end{array}$$

The first one doesn't seem right to me.

Isn't the second one the quantifier shift fallacy?

And the third one seems reasonable, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that none of those are are constructively provable and the first two aren't even classically provable if we allow an empty domain (which, admittedly, we usually don't).

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to rewrite the formulas rather than using an image so they are more accessible and discoverable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first does indeed not *seem* right ... but it is!  It is in fact the famous [Drinker Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox)

Why does it hold?  Here is an algebraic demonstration:

$\exists x (P(x) \to \forall y \ P(y)) \overset{Implication}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\exists x (\neg P(x) \lor \forall y \ P(y)) \overset{Distribution \ \exists \ over \ \lor}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\exists x  \neg P(x) \lor \exists x \forall y \ P(y) \overset{Quantifier \ Negation, Null\ Quantification}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\neg \forall x   P(x) \lor \forall y \ P(y) \overset{Replacing \ Variables}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\neg \forall x   P(x) \lor \forall x \ P(x) \overset{Complement}{\Leftrightarrow}$

$\top$

So, assuming your ND rules are complete, this is provable.

The second sequent also holds! While you are correct that in general you cannot swap quantifiers of different types, in this particular case you can. This is because the $Px$ only makes reference to the $x$, and not the $y$, and with $Qy$ ist is just the other way around. As such, you can bring the quantifiers inside, and both sides turn out to be equivalent to:

$\exists x \ Px \to \exists y \ Qy$

And yes, the third one also holds.

But in all cases: we would need to know exactly what rules you are using in order to know how to prove something like this.

Comment: Wow this is actually crazy! Never thought they were valid since they are so counterintuitive...

I'm using a Gentzen Style ND system, if it helps I could post all the rules.

Comment: @JakobRainer Yeah, these are pretty tricky so don't feel bad!  But yes, if you need help with the proofs, we'll need to know the actual rules, since there are many different proof systems, each with their own set of rules.

Comment: Sorry it took so long!
https://imgur.com/a/nscTO62
If you have any questions, just ask. Also, I would be more than happy with just one of those three :D

Comment: @JakobRainer Thanks for the rules ... this is actually not a style of system I am too experienced with.... also, you should really try and have a go at this yourself before seeking for help. I would recommend creating a new post (maybe even one for each different problem), where you give the rules, and also your attempt.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, although my attempts have been less than succesfull. One last question: is this one even valid? imgur.com/a/5lXOp6p

Comment: @JakobRainer  I have a hard time parsing that sentence ... what happens with the $x_1$? It looks like there is a predicate $A$, and a statement $Ax_1$ ... but this has obviously no relationship at all to the rest of the premises: are you sure you copied this correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is correctly copied. It is probably just there to throw one off. You can most than likely just leave it away.

Comment: @JakobRainer  Yeah, that makes sense. Indeed, all you need to prove the conclusion is to use the premise $Fa \lor Fb$. So, it is valid.

Comment: Thank you, you have been a huge help!

Comment: @JakobRainer You're welcome! :)